# What is the solution for streamlit error in cmd?

Tags: python, streamlit

I have made a python app with streamlit , also I installed streamlit successfully
When I try to run the command in cmd : streamlit run filename.py
the error occurs

```
"'streamlit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."
```

This is the error occuring what shoud I do to resolve this? please help me out!

Comment: you have to install streamlit using pip

Comment: @SandrinJoy I installed streamlit using pip successfully but in cmd its not working , but thanks for replying

Comment: Your streamlit install isn't done properly, check this out https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/getting-an-error-streamlit-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file/361/9

Comment: @queste thank you for replying I had resolved my error , thanks for your support.